# Expose a function using cherrypy with a path prefix

Tags: python, cherrypy

Is there a way in cherrypy to expose the function `foo_test()` as a `/foo/test` endpoint on the server?

The example below exposes two endpoints `/index` and `/foo_test`:

```
class Test(object):

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):

  @cherrypy.expose
  def foo_test(self):
```

Note:

- I have tested using alias in `@cherrypy.expose(['foo/test'])` but only strings and list of strings are allowed for an alias.

Comment: Did you check with the docs? Seems like this will do the trick for you http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/advanced.html#set-aliases-to-page-handlers

Comment: I have not seen the alias option but they only allow `single string or a list of them` so I cannot use `/`. Updated my question.

Comment: I got it, in the end I had to override the `_cp_dispatch`.

Comment: Docs always speak the truth, upvote you get ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I had to override the `_cp_dispatch` as explained in http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/advanced.html#the-special-cp-dispatch-method

```
class Test(object):

  def __init__(self):
       self.foo = Foo()

  def _cp_dispatch(self, vpath):
       if len(vpath) == 1:
            return self
       if len(vpath) == 2:
            return self.foo
       return self

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):

class Foo(object):

  @cherrypy.expose
  def test(self):
```